# Android, getting 4 linear layouts

Tags: android, layout

I am trying to get 4 linear layouts on the screen... but it only shows me the first two :(
(I'm a noob) here's my code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout1" 
    android:background="@drawable/background">
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout2" 
    android:background="@drawable/background_ass">
    </LinearLayout>

 <LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout3" 
    android:background="@drawable/background">
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout4" 
    android:background="@drawable/background_ass">
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: How do you know it's only showing the first 2? You're using the same 2 backgrounds in all 4 inner layouts.

Comment: The 4 backgrounds have a border... I have been able to resize them now via the graphical layout tool but it does not scale too well when i change sizes from QVGA upwards :(

Comment: Heh your background is named background_ass. Sorry I just had to do that. Carry on.

Comment: It may something related to your background images I suppose xml seems fine, I could say post background here but dont know what to expect from "background_ass" :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried setting the layout_weight to "1" on the 4 inner LinearLayouts?  Possibly something like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:orientation="vertical">
    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                  android:layout_weight="1"
                  android:background="#fafafa"/>
    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                  android:layout_weight="1"
                  android:background="#000000"/>
    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                  android:layout_weight="1"
                  android:background="#fafafa"/>
    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                  android:layout_weight="1"
                  android:background="#000000"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

This should share the available space between the layouts.

**Edited proposed XML**

Comment: I updated my XML in my answer to XML that I have confirmed to work.  Check it and see if it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

I think this might be because you might have too much content being shown in your first two linear layouts. Hence wrap_content for the first two layouts is taking up too much space on the screen. Try looking into that.

Comment: I have been able to resize them now via the graphical layout tool but it does not scale too well when i change sizes from QVGA upwards :(

Comment: Umm, check the xml. Are the sizes specified in dp?